# Row Editing in ExtJS Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am new to ExtJS.

I am trying to to add a row in my extjs grid with a handler associated to a image in one of my column. My row is getting added at specified index, but it doesn't automatically open in the edit mode. Could someone please help? I don't want to use the add button on the dock as shown in this link (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/row-editing.html)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

Ext.define('CallSequence', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
 fields: [
     'group',
     'attempt',
     'device', 
     'channel', 
     'deliveryContent',
     { name: 'vm', type: 'bool' },
     'delay'         
 ]
});

var callSequenceStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
      model: 'CallSequence' ,
      autoDestroy: false,
      data: [
        { "group": "1", "attempt": "1", "device":"Mobile", "channel":"SMS", "deliveryContent":"SMS Message","vm":false, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "1", "attempt": "2", "device":"Mobile", "channel":"Voice","deliveryContent":"Voice Script","vm":true, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "1", "attempt": "3", "device":"Work", "channel":"Voice", "deliveryContent":"Voice Script","vm":false, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "1", "attempt": "4", "device":"Home", "channel":"Voice", "deliveryContent":"Voice Script","vm":false, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "1", "attempt": "5", "device":"Other", "channel":"Voice", "deliveryContent":"Voice Script","vm":true, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "1", "attempt": "6", "device":"Email", "channel":"Email", "deliveryContent":"Email Message","vm":false, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "", "attempt": "", "device":"", "channel":"", "deliveryContent":"","vm":false, "delay":"30 mins"},
        { "group": "2", "attempt": "1", "device":"Mobile", "channel":"SMS", "deliveryContent":"SMS Message","vm":false, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "2", "attempt": "2", "device":"Mobile", "channel":"Voice","deliveryContent":"Voice Script","vm":false, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "2", "attempt": "3", "device":"Work", "channel":"Voice", "deliveryContent":"Voice Script","vm":false, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "2", "attempt": "4", "device":"Home", "channel":"Voice", "deliveryContent":"Voice Script","vm":false, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "2", "attempt": "5", "device":"Other", "channel":"Voice", "deliveryContent":"Voice Script","vm":false, "delay":"10 mins"},
        { "group": "2", "attempt": "6", "device":"Email", "channel":"Email", "deliveryContent":"Email Message","vm":false, "delay":"10 mins"}

    ]
}); 

   var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
       clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
       autoCancel: false
   });


var grid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
    renderTo: document.body,
    frame:true,
    title: 'Call Sequence',
    height:400,
    width:800,
    store: callSequenceStore,
    plugins: [rowEditing],
    columns: [
        {header: 'Group', dataIndex: 'group',editor: {allowBlank: true}},      
        {header: 'Attempt', dataIndex: 'attempt',editor: {allowBlank: true}},
        {header: 'Device', dataIndex: 'device',editor: {allowBlank: true}},
        {header: 'Channel Window', dataIndex: 'channel',editor: {allowBlank: true}},
        {header: 'Delivery Content', dataIndex: 'deliveryContent',editor: {allowBlank: true}},
        {header: 'Voice Message', dataIndex: 'vm',xtype: 'checkcolumn',editor: {xtype: 'checkbox',allowBlank: true},renderer : function(v, p, record){
              var delivertContentText = record.get('deliveryContent');
              if (delivertContentText == 'Voice Script'){ 
                  return (new Ext.ux.CheckColumn()).renderer(v);
              }
            }},
        {header: 'Delay', dataIndex: 'delay',editor: {allowBlank: true}},
        {header: 'Action',
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            align: 'center',
            width: 50,
            sortable: false,
            items: [ {
                icon: 'extJs/images/icons/fam/add.gif',
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    rowEditing.cancelEdit();
                    var newRow = Ext.create('CallSequence',{
                            group: '1',
                            attempt: '7',
                            device: '',
                            channel: '',
                            deliveryContent: '',
                            delay: ''
                    });
                    callSequenceStore.insert(rowIndex+1, newRow);
                    grid.getSelectionModel().select(newRow);
                    rowEditing.startEdit(newRow, 0);
                    //rowEditing.startEdit(callSequenceStore.getAt(rowIndex+1),0);
                    //grid.editingPlugin.startEdit(rowIndex+1);
                }

            },{
                icon: 'extJs/images/icons/fam/delete.gif',
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    callSequenceStore.removeAt(rowIndex);
                }
            },{
                icon: 'extJs/images/icons/fam/iconEdit.gif',
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    rowEditing.startEdit(0,0);
                }
            }]
        }
    ]
});
});
```

Comment: Could you show the code for `callSequenceStore` and `rowEditing`?

Comment: What version of ext are you using? I made a Sencha fiddle using your code, using Ext 4.2.1, and it does open row editing mode, but it doesn't focus on the first textfield.

Comment: I am using ext-js version 4.2.2

Comment: Well, the example you linked is for 4.1. I checked the same example in 4.2, and it doesn't auto focus on the textfields either. But it does open the editor, so I'm not sure why yours isn't working.

Comment: I don't want my current row to open in edit mode. I want my new row which got added just below the current row in edit mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to get this working by adding the following. clearListeners helped in clearing my event bubbling

```
rowEditing.startEdit(newRow,0);
rowEditing.clearListeners();
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `.startEdit` is not used the same way for editing an existing row and the newly added row.

In the edit handler your call it with two integers : `rowEditing.startEdit(0,0)`. This worked for me in my project.

In the add handler on the other hand, you call it with the record object `rowEditing.startEdit(newRow, 0)`. Try calling it with the record index instead : `rowEditing.startEdit(rowIndex + 1, 0)`.

While I'm not sure if this is the problem with your code, at least it is more consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is with event bubbling. When I use rowEditing.startEdit(newRow,0); my new row is coming to edit mode but it immediately goes back to the previous row because of the selection. I tried to use stopEvent, stopPropogation, return false etc.. still the contol goes back to previous row.. Could you please help ?